# Bash: find and replace text from a script

Tags: android, linux, bash, terminal

I need to modify a number into a file using a bash script

I want to remove a line that contains `dalvik.vm.heapsize=256` and replace it with a new line that contains `dalvik.vm.heapsize=512`. I not know the line number and 256 is an ipotetic value. How I can build a script that perform this action??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `sed` command:

```
sed -i -e 's/^\(dalvik.vm.heapsize=\).*/\1512/' build.prop
```

The command searches for a line starting with `dalvik.vm.heapsize=`, then replaces the part after `=` with `512`. The left part is captured using the regular expression group, and `\1` in the replacement part (`\1512`) refers to this group. The `-i` option instructs to replace in-place. Refer to `info sed` for details.

Here is a more advanced example taking into account possible leading spaces/tabs and making the match stricter by means of the regular expression lists:

```
sed -i -e 's/^\([ \t]*dalvik.vm.heapsize=\)[0-9]\+/\1512/' build.prop
```

Perl is more flexible. I prefer to use it for more complicated tasks. There is no such simple way as `sed`'s `-i` option for Perl, however; but you can simply use the shell redirection, e.g.:

```
cat build.prop | \
  perl -n -e 's/^([\t\s]*dalvik.vm.heapsize=)\d+/${1}512/; print' > build.prop
```